# Are the BMG snare and the inward K snare considered to be clap sounds?

Tags: beatbox

I'm new to beatbox and would like to know whether the BMG snare and the inward K snare are considered to be hand clap sounds?

Answer (score 1):

Within the category of snare sounds, I'd say they're closer to a rimshot or side-stick snare than to a hand clap or snare plus hand clap sound.

Using actual drums, this is a class of techniques that involve hitting the rim (the metal part around the drum skin) of the snare drum. It can be done as part of a normal hit, where the drum skin is hit with tip of the drum stick hits and the rim is hit with the middle of the stick at the same time, or by laying down the back end of the stick on the drum skin and the tip of the stick over the drum's edge, and then lifting the tip up and hitting the rim.

The names rimshot, rim-click, side-stick, and various other names are often used interchangeably for the different techniques, which can make it difficult to find the right sample or explain how a drum part should be played.

Comment: 99% of the time, "Rim shot" refers to the "normal hit" you describe, "side stick" refers to the "laying down" you describe.  These two techniques produce vastly different sounds, so they should not be used interchangeably.  (And proper technique says you should lay the *front* end of the stick down, not the back, unless you have no time to flip the stick).